# Shared variable between components

Tags: angular

Is there any way to have a shared variable between components in Angular 5. For example after login i want to have the id of user and pass it to other components to make some operations with this id. I want to avoid using sesseionStorage, localStorage or parameter. I want a variable that is not visible to the clients. I heard about @Input @output but i don't know the right way

Answer (score 2):

You can use Angular [Service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4) for that.

For example:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
    userId: number;
}
```

And then in some component:

```
@Component({...})
export class SomeComponent {
    constructor(private auth: AuthService) {
        // ...
    }

    // Do whatever you want with "userId" by using "this.auth.userId"
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering. i tested but when i reload the page the member userId is lost, it's become undefined, so i have to login another time that this member can have a value. i want a way that this member can be alive even if i reload the page like sessionStorage or localStorage but not accessible to the client, he can modify a sensible data

Comment: Of course it does, the moment you reload the page everything is restarted (that is why people use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` to preserve data on refresh)... I guess you can explore some other ways of preserving data (like _localdb_ or such) but none of those is perfectly safe (if that is what are you concerned about).

Comment: i am using Spring Boot Rest as backend app, and Angular as frontend app. can i use sessions to store usersId and some data that i need in the whole project ? a lot of clients can be logged in in the same time

Comment: i thought in a solution that consist of encrypting data then store it in the sessionStorage like that the user can't understand what is stored. the question is how to encrypt data(for example String) with Angular 5?? thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do that,

- `@Input` and `@OutPut` when you do not have a lot of a lost of nested components:

You have the `ParentComponent`, then you have the `ChildComponent`. So 1 Parent, 1 Child, I would use that.

If however if the structure more looks like `ParentComponent` -> `FirstLevelChildComponent` -> `SecondLevelChildComponent` , then if the values you want to access in `SecondLevelChildComponent` are from the `ParentComponent`, you need to go through `SecondLevelChildComponent` -> `FirstLevelChildComponent` -> `ParentComponent`. This is too much nesting, best practice do not go more than 1 level deep.

What is the solution to that:

- You can use a Service that gets injected in components.
- Use a StateManagement (Redux). This is only when you have a complex app.

For more information you can have a look at this article:

https://medium.com/@mirokoczka/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb

Comment: is the variables stored in @Input stay alive after refreshing the page?

Comment: No, nothing gets stored when you refresh. If you want to store them you need to use cookies, or local storage to persist that value . What are you trying to store?

If it is like a JWT token, then use Local Storage.